# Add logo at the middle of Navigation bar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add a logo in the middle of the navigation bar like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ToolbarItem  Icon="logo.png" Activated="RefButtonClicked"></ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I also tried this:

```
var cancelItem = new ToolbarItem
{
    Text = "Cancel",
    Icon = "tabalilogo.png",
    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary
};
```

Everything I tried positioned the logo on the right side of the navigation bar. How can I center it?

Comment: I think your question for android. It doesnt seem to be possible unless you disable toolbar and create your custom one. I had similar requirement and i ended up doing custom toolbar

Comment: @batmaci can you give me the instruction or reference ,because i never did a custom render before?

Comment: I dont mean custom renderer but custom toolbar. I give you as an answer.

Comment: What batmaci was talking about that instead of using ToolbarItem, you need to create page with ToolbarItem disabled and draw TabBar alike view on the top of your view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently After Updating to xamarin forms 3.2, You can customize the title bar using title bar property.

```
     <ContentPage>
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10">
        <Image Source="iconXamagon.png">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <Image.TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="HandleTapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Label Text="3.2.0" FontSize="16" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
....
```

For more details https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-2-0-released-going-big-with-little-things/

Comment: Doing this, the logo is located slightly to the right off the center, if there is a menu or back button on the left of the navigation bar. It looks absolutely horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that can be implemented using existing toolbar but I had similar requirement and I couldn't figure out how to achieve using the xamarin forms toolbar on a navigation page. therefore I decided to use a modal page and I disabled the navigation page in the code behind with the line of code below.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

I am using xaml and I created a custom navigator with absolutelayout as below

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="slToolbar"  Grid.Row="0" >
        <Button x:Name="Cancel" BackgroundColor="#ADD8E6" Image="cancel.png" Command="{Binding CancelClick}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
          <AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle" iOS="0, .5, 36, 36" Android="0, .5, 36, 36" WinPhone="0, .5, 50, 50" />
          </AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
        </Button>


        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
           <AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle" iOS="1,.5,110,50" Android="1,.5,50,36" WinPhone="1,.5,110,50" />
          </AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>


          <ContentView >
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
              <OnPlatform.iOS>
                <Button   x:Name="NewIOS"  BackgroundColor="#ADD8E6" Image="ic_add.png" Command="{Binding AddNew}"  ></Button>
              </OnPlatform.iOS>
              <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                <Button   x:Name="NewWP"  BackgroundColor="#ADD8E6"  Command="{Binding AddNew}"  Image="ic_add.png"/>
              </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
            </OnPlatform>
          </ContentView>


          <Button   x:Name="btnSave"  BackgroundColor="#ADD8E6" Image="check.png" Command="{Binding SaveClick}"   HorizontalOptions="End" ></Button>
        </StackLayout>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
```

this code will produce something like below. I have the icons in the corners but surely they can be placed anywhere. I used cancel icon instead of back button. Of course, in this case you need to handle back button(cancel button) click yourself. screenshot below is from uwp application but on android and ios I get similar results.

[image]

Comment: i figured out what you was mean , i will try this

Comment: @AhmedSayed  Onn my android project, i prefer to use side menu but on UWP I use tabbed page and it looks fine for me. I dont think this is any different than XF default toolbar. Imagine instead of X button on the left, you have back button as arrow.